# Show dynamical system $([0,1],T_2)$ is exact

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Consider the dynamical system $([0,1],T_2)$, where $T_2$ is the tent map given by
$$T_2(x)=  \begin{cases} 
      2x & x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}] \\
      2(1-x) & x \in [\frac{1}{2},1]
   \end{cases}.$$
Let $I \subseteq [0,1]$ be an interval such that $I$ is not a singleton. 

 I need to show that $([0,1],T_2)$ is exact, i.e. for any non-empty open subset $U \subseteq [0,1]$, there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $T_2^n[U]=[0,1]$.

 I have previously shown that if $\frac{1}{2} \notin I$, then there must exist an integer $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{2} \in T_2^n[I]$. I did this by considering the lengths of intervals $T_2^n[U]$ and arriving at a contradiction.

 I think I need to use connectedness somehow, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Any non-empty open subset $U$ contains a closed interval $[a,b]$ with $a\neq b$. Prove that $T^n_2$ maps $[k/2^n,(k+1)/2^n]$ to $[0,1]$ bijectively for each $k=0,\ldots,2^n-1$. Just take $n$ large enough so that there is some $k$ with $[k/2^n,(k+1)/2^n]\subseteq [a,b]$.